# Edit list of items moving "The" to end of line

Tags: microsoft-word, notepad++

I want to produce a hard copy of my media library. I produced text file using the DOS `DIR /B` command and then used MS Word to format it. However, there is a very significant difference between this list and the one displayed on screen by the Kodi Media Cantre app, There, all leading definite and indefinite articles are transferred to the end of each item, eg."The War of the Worlds" becomes "War of the Worlds, The".

I have googled extensively and looked at MS & Open Office and NPP++ but none have built in routines. Is there a macro or plug-in that will do this?

Comment: Why not find and replace instances of 'The' with nothing, in Word, then they should mostly align with what you see in Kodi?  Or change Kodi options System\Appearance\File Lists\Ignore articles when sorting (e.g. "the")

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## With Notepad++

- Find What: `^(The)(\s)((.)+)$`
- Replace with: `$3, $1`
- Search mode: Regular Expression

**Before**

[image: IMG:]

**After**

[image: IMG:]